# Using max function

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have two tables:

```
TotalTimeTable
(date date,time time)

FinalListA
(date date, time time, A int, B int)
```

I am running the following query:

```
SELECT t1.date,
       t1.time,
       max(t2.time)
FROM TotalTimeTable t1,
     FinalListA t2
WHERE t2.date=t1.date
  AND t2.time <= t1.time
GROUP BY t1.date,
         t1.time
ORDER BY t1.date,
         t1.time
```

Is there a way to pull out A and B from FinalListA where time = "max(t2.time)" in the same query?

TotalTimeTable:

```
date        time    
2006-01-01  9:30:01     
2006-01-01  9:30:02 
2006-01-01  9:30:03
2006-01-01  9:30:04
2006-01-01  9:30:05 
2006-01-01  9:30:06
```

FinalListA:

```
date        time     A B
2006-01-01  9:28:01  1 4
2006-01-01  9:30:02  2 3
2006-01-01  9:30:04  4 7
2006-01-01  9:30:07  6 4
2006-01-01  9:30:10  8 9
2006-01-01  9:30:11  1 2
```

The expected result is:

```
date        time     A B
2006-01-01  9:30:01  1 4
2006-01-01  9:30:02  2 3
2006-01-01  9:30:03  2 3
2006-01-01  9:30:04  4 7
2006-01-01  9:30:05  4 7
2006-01-01  9:30:06  4 7
```

The time is from TotalTimeTable
FinalListA.time don't have to be in the result.

Comment: Please, provide sample rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using cross apply:

```
SELECT t1.date
   , t1.time
   , t2.time
   , t2.A
   , t2.B
FROM TotalTimeTable t1
CROSS APPLY (
 SELECT TOP(1)
  T2.time
 , T2.A
 , T2.B
FROM FinalListA t2
WHERE T2.date = T1.date
AND T2.time <= t1.time
ORDER BY T2.time DESC
) AS T2
ORDER BY t1.date,
     t1.time
```

Comment: Sorry, didn't had time to test it yet

Comment: The result is correct but it is a little bit slower than of @techdo

Answer (score 1):

Please try:

```
SELECT t1.date,
       t1.time,
       (select top 1 t2.A from FinalListA t2 where t2.date=t1.date and t2.Time<=t1.Time order by t2.Time desc) A,
       (select top 1 t2.B from FinalListA t2 where t2.date=t1.date and t2.Time<=t1.Time order by t2.Time desc) B
FROM TotalTimeTable t1
```

or using left join

```
select 
    x.date,
    x.Time,
    x.A,
    x.B
from(
    SELECT t1.*,
           t2.A,
           t2.B,
           ROW_NUMBER() over (PARTITION BY t1.date, t1.time order by t2.time desc) RNum
    FROM TotalTimeTable t1 left join
         FinalListA t2 on t1.date=t2.date and t2.Time<=t1.Time
)x where RNum=1
```

or using CROSS APPLY

```
SELECT t1.date,
       t1.time, 
       x.*
FROM TotalTimeTable t1 cross apply (
SELECT TOP 1 t2.A, t2.B from FinalListA t2 where t2.date=t1.date and t2.Time<=t1.Time order by t2.Time desc)x
```

Comment: Please add sample data, and expected output.

Comment: I've added sample data just now, i'll add expected output in a minute

Comment: Please check the edited answer using sub-query and left join.

Comment: Is there a way to do 2 top 1 select together? 
Besides, first query is the quickest and the results are correct.

Comment: Please check the result using `CROSS APPLY`.

Comment: Yes his cross apply is far better than mine because... they're the same.

Comment: My mistake Serge but it was slower first time that I've run it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use your original query as a constraining subquery (without the ORDER BY)

```
SELECT t1.Date, t1.Time, t2.Time, t2.A, t2.B
FROM TotalTimeTable t1
INNER JOIN 
(
    SELECT t1.date,
           t1.time,
           maxt2Time = max(t2.time)
    FROM TotalTimeTable t1,
         FinalListA t2
    WHERE t2.date=t1.date
      AND t2.time <= t1.time
    GROUP BY t1.date,
             t1.time
) tmax
ON t1.Date = tmax.date AND t1.Time = tmax.Time
INNER JOIN FinalListA t2 ON t2.Date = tmax.Date AND t2.Time = tmax.maxt2Time
```

Comment: @Serge's cross-apply below is about 50% faster

Comment: Yes, this is how I'm planning to do it, but I want to check if there is simpler/faster query than this.

Comment: Could reduce the the subquery to INNER JOIN (SELECT date, time = max(time) from FinalListA GROUP BY date) tmax